# Enable automatic key rotation for keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-role-environment

I've been working on a solution to implement automatic key rotation for a storage account using keyvault. The script I'm using is listed below. The object ID is not a service principal (its my ObjectID).

```
$resourcegroup = "resourcegroupname"
$saname = "storageaccountname"
$vaultname = "keyvaultname"

$storage = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup - 
StorageAccountName $saname

$userPrincipalId = $(Get-AzureRmADUser -ObjectId "my-object-id").Id

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId $userPrincipalId -RoleDefinitionName 
'Storage Account Key Operator Service Role' -Scope $storage.Id

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $vaultname -ObjectId $userPrincipalId - -PermissionsToStorage all
$regenPeriod = [System.Timespan]::FromDays(1)

Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName $vaultname -AccountName 
$saname -AccountResourceId $storage.Id -ActiveKeyName key2 -RegenerationPeriod $regenPeriod
```

But then I get the following error

```
Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount : Key vault service doesn't have proper permissions to access the storage account 
https://something.vault.azure.net/storage/something
At line:17 char:1
+ Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName $vaultname -Account ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount], KeyVaultErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.AddAzureKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to assign **Storage Account Key Operator Service Role** to KeyVault's Service principal on the storage account.

Refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys#setup-for-role-based-access-control-rbac-permissions)